# Ajax Response is very slow in IE only, working fine in Firefox chrome and other modern browsers why?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

An ajax response is taking 25.33 seconds in IE11 and ie10 but in other browsers it is taking only 5.71 seconds.

By this until the response is not coming from server page area is empty and it seems buggy for a normal user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In IE, I can only send request to server 7 times maximum when using ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830015/in-ie-i-can-only-send-request-to-server-7-times-maximum-when-using-ajax)